# Console.log in loader.min.js

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

In current revision of `loader.min.js` there is a `console.log()` call left in the end of the file: http://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/gethired/loader.min.js?36a8c9

```
... n=(new Date).getMilliseconds()>1e3;console.log(n);setTimeout(A,2e3);if(n){o();return}c=setTimeout(i,j)})();
                                       ^--------
```

**UPD**: took it from the main of http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Rebecca Chernoff: forgot to mention - it is taken from stackoverflow.com, not careers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like opened questions - so answer here myself: fixed